# Best solution for managing navigation (and marking currently active item) in CakePHP

Tags: list, cakephp, plugins, model, navigation

So I have been looking around for a couple hours for a solid solution to handling site navigation in CakePHP.  Over the course of a dozen projects, I have rigged together something that works for each one, but what I'm looking for is ideally a CakePHP plugin that handles the following:

- Navigation Model
- Component for handing off to the view
- Element View Helper for displaying the navigation (with control over sublevels displayed and automatically determining the "active" item based on URL and/or controller/model/slug
- Admin pages for managing a tree of navigation

Any suggestions for an all-in-one solution or even the individual components would be very appreciated!  Or even suggestions on how you have handled it in the past

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue at work recently and i ended up whiping up a helper that would take query from the contents table and convert that into a menu. As it needed to become more flexible the code got worse and worse up to the point where i am currently rewriting it.

Don't hold your breath though as i will be taking my time to make it work right as it needs to be very flexible but it cant be confusing to use.